# Balancing slow I/O in a fast stream read stream

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, stream

In node.js I have a read stream that I wish to reformat and write to a database. As the read stream is fast and the write is slow the node.js queue could be overwhelmed as the queue of writes builds up (assume the stream is gb's of data). How do I force the read to wait for the write part of the code so this does not happen without blocking ?

```
var request = http.get({
      host: 'api.geonames.org',
      port: 80,
      path: '/children?' + qs.stringify({
      geonameId: geonameId,
      username: "demo"
   })
}).on('response', function(response) {
   response.setEncoding('utf8');
   var xml = new XmlStream(response, 'utf8');

   xml.on('endElement: geoname ', function(input) {  
      console.log('geoname');
      var output = new Object();
      output.Name = input.name;
      output.lat = input.lat;
      output.lng = input.lng;
      output._key = input.geonameId;
      data.db.document.create(output, data.doc, function(callback){    
         //this is really slow.
      }
      // i do not want to return from here and receive more data until the 'create' above has completed
   });  
});
```

Comment: it is, that's not the problem. for large data streams as the write is slow the node queue is overwhelmed and you end with an out of memory exception.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem last night, and in my hackathon induced sleep deprived state, here is how I solved it:

I would increment a counter whenever I sent a job out to be processed, and decremented the counter when the operation completed. To keep the outbound traffic from overwhelming the other service, I would pause the stream when there was a certain number of pending outbound requests. The code is very similar to the following.

```
var instream = fs.createReadStream('./combined.csv');
var outstream = new stream;
var inProcess = 0;
var paused = false;
var rl = readline.createInterface(instream, outstream);
rl.on('line', function(line) {
    inProcess++;
    if(inProcess > 100) {
        console.log('pausing input to clear queue');
        rl.pause();
        paused = true;
    }

    someService.doSomethingSlow(line, function() {
        inProcess--;
        if(paused && inProcess < 10) {
            console.log('resuming stream');
            paused = false;
            rl.resume();
        }

        if (err) throw err;
    });
});

rl.on('end', function() {
    rl.close();
});
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it worked and allowed me to process the million+ lines without running out of memory or throttling the other service.

Comment: interesting. though i think as soon as you use 'pause' you are forced to revert to streams1 rather than the current streams2. glad it's not just me stuck on this ! i'd have thought more people would have encountered the problem given this is what streams are meant to solve!

Comment: See my answer for a similar solution that extends `stream.Writable` and uses events, rather than `.pause()`/`.resume()`, to control the ingestion rate.

Answer (score 0):

My solution simply extends an empty `stream.Writable` and is fundamentally identical to @Timothy's, but uses events and
doesn't rely on Streams1 `.pause()` and `.resume()` (which didn't seem to be having any effect on my data pipeline,
anyway).

```
var stream = require("stream");

var liveRequests = 0;
var maxLiveRequests = 100;
var streamPaused = false;

var requestClient = new stream.Writable();

function requestCompleted(){
    liveRequests--;
    if(streamPaused && liveRequests < maxLiveRequests){
        streamPaused = false;
        requestClient.emit("resumeStream");
    }
}

requestClient._write = function (data, enc, next){
    makeRequest(data, requestCompleted);
    liveRequests++;

    if(liveRequests >= maxLiveRequests){
        streamPaused = true;
        requestClient.once("resumeStream", function resume(){
            next();
        });
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
};
```

A counter, `liveRequests`, keeps track of the number of concurrent requests, and is incremented whenever
`makeRequest()` is called and decremented when it completes (ie, when `requestCompleted()`) is called. If a request has
just been made and `liveRequests` exceeds `maxLiveRequests`, we pause the stream with `streamPaused`. If a request
completes, the stream is paused, and `liveRequests` is now less than `maxLiveRequests`, we can resume the stream. Since
subsequent data items are read by `_write()` when its `next()` callback is called, we can simply defer the latter with
an event-listener on our custom `"resumeStream"` event, which mimics pausing/resuming.
Now, simply `readStream.pipe(requestClient)`.

---

Edit: I abstracted this solution, along with automatic batching of input data, in a [package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/batch-request-stream).